# Sentry 2: Using multiple login attributes

Tags: authentication, laravel, cartalyst-sentry

I have been using Sentry for a little while now and I think it is very useful. However, currently I need to be able to let the user log in to the application using their email or username. Due to Sentry's usage of exceptions a simple loop won't cut it since it will quit in the first run. Does anybody have a good idea on how to tackle this issue?